# RowDataPacket Returning Undefined Value

Tags: mysql, node.js, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure to insert into the db and return the order id to the console after insert.

Here is my Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE create_old_user_order(
IN p_userid      int(11),
IN p_userfname   varchar(50),
IN p_userlname   varchar(50),
IN p_phone       varchar(20),
IN p_item        int(11),
IN p_item_qty    int(11))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO user_order(customer_id,
                   first_name,
                   last_name,
                   phone_numb,
                   order_item,
                   order_quantity)
    VALUES (p_userid,
            p_userfname,
            p_userlname,
            p_phone,
            p_item,
            p_item_qty);

  SET @LAST_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

  SELECT @LAST_id AS `booking_id`;
  END;
```

Calling the procedure from Node.js Express app is fine.

```
     console.log(results)
```

shows this

```
       [ [ RowDataPacket { booking_id: 15646747643 } ],
       OkPacket {
        fieldCount: 0,
        affectedRows: 0,
         insertId: 0,
         serverStatus: 2,
          warningCount: 0,
            message: '',
           protocol41: true,
             changedRows: 0 } ]
```

and

```
       console.log(results[0])
```

shows this:

```
      [ RowDataPacket { booking_id: 15646747643 } ]
```

doing this

```
       console.log(results[0].booking_id)
```

i get

```
         Undefined.
```

PLEASE HELPPPP

Answer (score 1):

got it fixed. Should have accessed it this way

```
 results[0][0].booking_id
```